# Boolean algebra does not simplify

Tags: boolean-computation

I am doing some simple Boolean algebra and wanted to perform some calculations in *Mathematica* but found it doesn't work.

Let us consider the expression:

```
expr1 = ((b < 0 && A <= AA) || A < AA);
expr2 = ((b < 0 && A == AA) || A < AA);
```

From our point of view they are the same.  Or do we miss a special case?

```
FullSimplify[{expr1 == expr2}, #] & /@ {A < AA, A > AA, A == AA}
```

> {{True}, {True}, {True}}

Now the problem is *Mathematica* does not see them as equivalent, in general:

```
FullSimplify[
expr1
 ==
expr2
,
A > 0 && AA > 0]
```

This does not yield `True`, but instead `expr1 == expr2`.

Do we have an error in reasoning?

How can I make *Mathematica* simplify `expr1` to `expr2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Equivalent[expr1, expr2] // FullSimplify

(* True*)
```

Comment: Whats the difference to my code?

Comment: @Philipp `Equivalent` does not mean `Equal`.It only means that the truth tables for both are the same

Answer (score 2):

Just to amplify belisarius comments, let
b<0 be x, 
A < AA be y 
and A==AA be z,

then your expressions are:

```
e1 = (x && (y || z)) || z
e2 = (x && y) || z
```

`BooleanMinimize` applied to these yields: (x && y) || z

The truth tables can be shown:

```
Framed@TableForm[BooleanTable[{x, y, z, e1, e2}], 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {x, y, z, e1, e2}}]
```

[image]

And `TautologyQ[Equivalent[e1, e2]]` yields `True`.